# Unhandled Exception: Access violation writing location 0x00000000

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am doing a simple application to define a structure and place data in tha structure to learn the concept of structures. But when trying to insert data to structure i am getting an access violation. Following is the code portions.

In Test.h file

```
typedef struct Msg
{
unsigned char*   message_id;
unsigned char*   message_name;
}Msg_t;
```

In Test.cpp file

```
Msg_t *new_node[10];

const char *src = "E0";
new_node[0]->message_id = (unsigned char *)_strdup(src); //getting access violation error here.
```

Why am i getting error? Please help.

Comment: `Msg_t *new_node[10];` You never initialize the pointers in this array.

Comment: I tried iniitializing the array as Msg_t *new_node[10] = {0}; But still getting error.

Comment: You have do use `new Msg_t()` to get valid pointers into each array element.

Comment: I highly recommend you stop trying to learn C++ by trial and error. It will get you nowhere. Learn it systematically from a good book or tutorial instead.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ He most likely does not need an array of pointers in the first place. Looks like he has no idea what he is doing.

Comment: Please help.. I am totally new to this environment.. I know this is stupid question.. This is just a part of actual code. If you knw please help

Comment: _@AnuJacob_ I'd recommend you should follow @Baum 's advice.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Sure.. I am learning C++ now only.. I found an example and im trying to compile it.. Please help if you know how to do it. Thanks.

Comment: @AnuJacob Sorry to say that, you may have a misconception what the Stack Overflow site is about. It's not a personal helpdesk. You may check the help center to [learn asking better questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). Also I already told you what's necessary to do in my other comment. You should research about this a bit before using it.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I knw its not personal help desk, but you can help people in need  atleast with wat you know. anyway thank u for all ur valuable comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer by myself. Its the issue with no proper initialization. I added following line to my code.

```
new_node[0] = new Msg_t();
new_node[0]->message_id = (unsigned char *)_strdup(src);
```

Now everything works perfectly.